# SQL Server Charset / Encoding Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, character-encoding, code-first

The problem is that when I save text into a SQL Server database, I have problems with charset / encoding.

The text has `ä ö ü` (German umlaut) letters. In myLittleAdmin, I see `�` instead of the proper `ä ö ü` letters.

My host just gives me access to database by myLittleAdmin. How and where can I configure the charset / encoding?

Comment: No idea what "myLittleAdmin" is, but check through EF.  Your string properties should map to NVarchar columns, which which uses the Unicode character set will have no problem with german letters.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: even a "normal" `varchar` column will not have any problems with German umlauts.....

Comment: Yep.  For the common collations.  You can dump the characters for a varchar encoding like this     
                                                                                                                              

     with q as
    (
      select top 256 row_number() over (order by (select null))-1 i
      from sys.objects, sys.columns
    )
select cast( cast(i as binary(1)) as varchar(1)) collate Latin1_General_BIN i
from q